# Angularjs filter list data using select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've json data in following format:
{
    "id": "mypics-1",
    "imageThumbUrl": "img/small/1.jpg",
    "imageUrl": "img/large/1.jpg",
    "name": "1.jpg",
    "type": "imgage"
}, {
    "id": "mypics-2",
    "imageThumbUrl": "img/small/2.jpg",
    "imageUrl": "img/large/2.jpg",
    "name": "2.jpg",
    "type": "image"
}

I need to filter image list on type base if user selects the selects a value from drop down. My code is as follows. I tried many ways but it didn't filtering data, rather it empties the list.

```
                        <select ng-model="showGenre">
                            <option value=" " selected>All</option>
                            <option ng-repeat="type in ImageTypes" value="{{type.name}}">{{type.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="myPicsDivCls">
                            <ul id="carousel2" class="elastislide-list">
                                <li ng-repeat="ImageFile in ImageFiles | filter: {type:showGenre}">
                                    <a>
                                        <img ng-src="{{ImageFile.imageThumbUrl}}" data-echo="{{ImageFile.imageThumbUrl}}" alt="image06" />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<li ng-repeat="ImageFile in ImageFiles | filter: showGenre">
```

//----------EDIT-----------//
try

```
<li ng-repeat="ImageFile in ImageFiles | showGenre">
```

//----------EDIT----------------//
change

```
<option value=" " selected>All</option>
```

to

```
 <option value="" selected>All</option>
```

i think is due to that

Comment: No still it just empty the list.

Comment: No it's not filtering the list.